# Populate jquery list from SQL query result using MVC / razor

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller action which passes in a SQL query result to the view

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Register(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel
        {
            Organisations = _context.Organisations.ToList(),
        };
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The view is a registration page which asks for the users email address. I want the email address to autofill with the domain relevant to their organisation after they type "@" - this is facilitated by [jquery.email-autocomplete.js](https://github.com/10w042/email-autocomplete#jqueryemail-autocompletejs-v011) 
 - Example image of input field in use:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLUal.png)

There are about 50 organisations and they are stored in a database table which is structured like:

```
ID | Name    | EmailDomain         
-----------------------------------
1    My Org    myorganisation.co.uk
```

I need a way to dynamically get the email domains from the organisation object into this bit of jquery code in the view:

```
<script>
$("#email").emailautocomplete({
  suggClass: "custom-classname", //default: "eac-sugg". your custom classname (optional)
  domains: ["example.com"] //additional domains (optional)
});
</script>
```

So when rendered, the line of code for domains needs to look something like:

```
domains: ["myorganisation.co.uk", "anotherorganisation.org.uk", "andanother.com"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing

```
$("#email").emailautocomplete({
domains: [@foreach (var organisation in Model.Organisations)
             {
                @Html.Raw("\"") @organisation.EmailDomain 
                @Html.Raw("\", \r\n") 
             }
                @Html.Raw("]")
});
```

Which renders as:

```
$("#Email").emailautocomplete({
domains: ["domain1.gov.uk", 
"domain2.com", 
"domain3.gov.uk", 
"domain4.gov.uk", 
] 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an action result in your controller to handle the autocomplete. Something like:

```
    public ActionResult AutocompleteEmail(string text)
    {
        var filteredItems = MethodToLookupDBValues(text);
        return Json(filteredItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

You can then call it from js like so:

```
        $('#email').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("AutocompleteEmail")', {
                    text: request.term
                }, response);
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#selectedItem').val(ui.item.id);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but not entirely sure how to implement. Would "source: " be where I put "domains: " in my case? Also I was hoping to make use of the organisations list already passed into the view to save another round trip to the database.